# Understanding the semantics of subquery in FROM clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `rttmm` table with `conversation_id` and `duration` fields. There's a query using two sub-queries in a `FROM`-clause, one of them is not used. I would expect it to be semantically equivalent to the one where you would remove the unused subquery, but it behaves very differently. Here's the query in question:

```sql
select
  sum(subq2.dur) as res
    from (
      select sum(rttmm.duration) as dur, rttmm.conversation_id as conv_id
      from rttmm
      group by rttmm.conversation_id
      ) as subq1,
    (
      select sum(rttmm.duration) as dur, rttmm.conversation_id as conv_id
      from rttmm
      group by rttmm.conversation_id
    ) as subq2
```

and here's what I would expect it to be equivalent to (just removing the subq1):

```sql
select
  sum(subq2.dur) as res
    from 
    (
      select sum(rttmm.duration) as dur, rttmm.conversation_id as conv_id
      from rttmm
      group by rttmm.conversation_id
    ) as subq2
```

Turns out it's not the same at all. What is the proper understanding of the first query here?

Comment: The first one will perform a cross-join. (If the first subquery returns 4 rows, and the second 3 rows, they will return 12 rows cross-joined.)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN`  syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Remember, too, even if you do not `SELECT` from a source in `FROM` or `JOIN`, all underlying tables are being used some way!

Comment: @jarlh thanks! I don't need any `JOIN` in the final code, basically needed to do two queries separately and combine their results. Ended up join doing two queries and combining the results not via SQL.

Comment: (IMHO) While separating into 2 queries and combining the results externally worked in this case, I would caution you this is a very very poor habit to get into. SQL is designed for set processing, and is quite good at it. Suppose instead of 4 rows and 3 rows, your result set was 4M rows and 3M rows. SQL while taking quite a while would handle the resulting 12T rows. Would your external process? Start thinking in terms of sets when dealing with SQL In this case just do the appropriate join.

Comment: @Belayer sure, the results I get from new 2-query implementation are both just a single number, so I don't think any danger there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query uses the ancient [SQL-89 join syntax](https://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/oracle-sql-programming/basic-sql-join-semantics/) and cross-joins two subqueries, whereas the second query does a simple select from the first subquery.

In simple words, the difference is:

`select * from table1, table2` vs `select * from table1`

which is equivalent for

`select * from table1 cross join table2` vs `select * from table1`

Comment: Thank you! I don't think I want any kind of `JOIN` here, ended up just doing two queries and counting the result on server.